# The C program is not displaying any output but it take the input Question from CS50 Lab1

Tags: c, while-loop, cs50

Say we have a population of n llamas. Each year, n / 3 new llamas are born, and n / 4 llamas pass away.

For example, if we were to start with n = 1200 llamas, then in the first year, 1200 / 3 = 400 new llamas would be born and 1200 / 4 = 300 llamas would pass away. At the end of that year, we would have 1200 + 400 - 300 = 1300 llamas.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // TODO: Prompt for start size
    int a, b;
    do
    {
        printf("Start Size: ");
        scanf("%i", &a);
    }
    while (a < 9);
    // TODO: Prompt for end size
    do
    {
        printf("End Size: ");
        scanf("%i", &b);
    }
    while (b < a);
    // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
    int y = 0;
    while (a < b)
    {
        a = round((float)a + (a / 4) - (a / 3));
        y++;
    }

    // TODO: Print number of years
    printf("Years: %i\n", y);
}
```

The Input I tried and output I expected:

1. Start size: 1200
   End size: 1300
   Years: 1
2. Start size: -5
   Start size: 3
   Start size: 9
   End size: 5
   End size: 18
   Years: 8
3. Start size: 20
   End size: 1
   End size: 10
   End size: 100
   Years: 20
4. Start size: 100
   End size: 1000000
   Years: 115

Comment: The expressions `a / 4` and `a / 3` are *integer* expressions, with an *integer* result. If you divide `7` by `4` the result will be `1`, not `1.75`.

Comment: You could solve this by Math, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is incorrect: you swapped the number of newly born llamas and the number of deceased ones. This formula converges to `0` and causes an infinite loop once `a` reaches a value between 0 and 2 and does not change anymore.

Write this instead:

```
a = round((float)a + (a / 3) - (a / 4));
```

Note that you should use plain integer arithmetics as the number of new llamas and dead llamas are whole numbers. Since `a` in an `int`, so are `a / 3` and `a / 4`, no need for a `(float)` cast or a `round()` function call:

```
a = a + a / 3 - a / 4;
```

or simpler:

```
a += a / 3 - a / 4;
```

Note also that you should test the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior in case of invalid or missing input.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Prompt for start size
    int a, b;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Start Size: ");
        if (scanf("%i", &a) != 1) {
            int c;
            printf("invalid input\n");
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
            if (c == EOF)
                printf("unexpected end of file\n");
                return 1;
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (a < 9) {
            printf("value must be at least 9\n");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    // Prompt for end size
    for (;;) {
        printf("End Size: ");
        if (scanf("%i", &b) != 1) {
            int c;
            printf("invalid input\n");
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
            if (c == EOF)
                printf("unexpected end of file\n");
                return 1;
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (b < a) {
            printf("value must be at least %d\n", a);
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    // Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
    int y = 0;
    while (a < b) {
        a += a / 3 - a / 4;
        y++;
    }

    // Print number of years
    printf("Years: %i\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

As you are taking the CS50 course, you should use the function `get_int()` from `<cs50.h>` to simplify the error handling in a convenient manner:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Prompt for start size
    int a, b;

    while ((a = get_int("Start Size: ")) < 9) {
        printf("value must be at least 9\n");
    }

    // Prompt for end size
    while ((b = get_int("End Size: ")) < a) {
        printf("value must be at least %d\n", a);
    }

    // Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
    int y = 0;
    while (a < b) {
        a += a / 3 - a / 4;
        y++;
    }

    // Print number of years
    printf("Years: %i\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the while loop

```
a = round((float)a + (a / 4) - (a / 3));
```

It seems you mean

```
a = round((float)a - (a / 4) + (a / 3));
```

Also casting to float the variable `a` does not make sense. Instead you could write for example

```
a = round(a - (a / 4.0) + (a / 3.0));
```

Comment: I'm afraid your proposed solution is not correct.  The assignment does not specify if the numbers of new and dead llamas are to be rounded or truncated.  your implementation rounds the result, which is consistent with the OP's code but not consistent with either rounding method for each of `n / 3` and `n / 4`.   The computation should be either `a += a / 3 - a / 4` or  `a += round(a / 3.0) - round(a / 4.0)`.

Comment: @chqrlie There is no sense to write round( a / 4.0 ). It is the result value that is rounded. Actually using round  round( a / 4.0 ) is incorrect.

Comment: I disagree: `round(a/4.0)` would be required if the assignment specified that the number of new llamas should be rounded to the nearest, and still that would not be precise enough as *rounding* is still ambiguous for values exactly half way between 2 integers.  Lacking such precision, I think the number of new and dead llamas should be truncated, hence rounding toward `0`, which `a = round(a - (a / 4.0) + (a / 3.0))` does not perform correctly: `round(a - b)` is not the same as `round(a) - round(b)`

Comment: @chqrlie I can agree with you only relative to one thing that round( a ) - round( b ) is not the same as round( a - b ). Now run these statements    printf( "round( 0.4999 ) = %f\n", round( 0.4999 ) );
  printf( "round( 0.5 ) = %f\n", round( 0.5 ) ); and see their results. According to your approach round( 0.5) - round( 0.4999 ) will be equal to 1 that is not a correct approach.

Comment: For `a = 15`, `a + a/3 - a/4` produces `17`, whereas `round(a - (a / 4.0) + (a / 3.0))` gives `round(15 - 3.75 + 5.0)` -> `round(16.25)` -> `16`. Which one do you consider correct ?

Comment: @chqrlie  In my opinion the correct result is when the integer arithmetic is used.

Comment: I agree, so you should **not** suggest `a = round(a - (a / 4.0) + (a / 3.0));` as a solution.

Comment: @chqrlie I just rewrote his statement correctly.:)